# Error parsing script headers in admin-ajax with an HTTP request

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am working on Wordpress and I have a strange error. This is my jQuery code

```
add_to_my_cart: function () {
            $(document).on('submit', 'form.form-submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();              
                var data = $(this).serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url     : wp_custom_settings.ajax,
                    type    : 'POST',
                    data    : data,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success : function (code) {
                        code = parseJSON(code);
                        window.location.href = code.redirect;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

The above is called when I submit a form and pass some data to the PHP function. However, I get a `500 internal server error` on admin-ajax HTTP request, with the following on apache logs.

```
Premature end of script headers: admin-ajax.php, referer: my.domain.here
AH01070: Error parsing script headers, referer: my.domain.here
```

I used the `error_log($message)` in every step of the process and I haven't found any problem. The very last step is the return of the JSON request.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_send_json' ) ) {

function my_send_json( $data ) {
    error_log("DONE");
    @header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
    echo '<!-- WP_AJAX_START -->';
    echo wp_json_encode( $data );
    echo '<!-- WP_AJAX_END -->';
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        wp_die();
    } else {
        die;
    }
}
}
```

I can see on the `debug.log` the string `DONE`, but the HTTP request has an empty response. I tried also to remove the `$data` and just return this

```
echo wp_json_encode( array( 'status' => 'success', 'redirect' => 'my.domain.here' ));
```

But still the same. I cannot think of any other way to debug it.

Comment: have you provided action value in your form?

Comment: Yes. I added it as a hidden input like this `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="wp_custom_add_to_my_cart">`

Comment: Your code is similar to the core one. Why did you copy all but status header?  Maybe just switch to build one https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/

Comment: I tried also with the built-in `wp_send_json` but I have the same behavior. The reason I created my own is that I will need to add some extra features there later.